# Adding Bleed to an irregular shape illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, bleed

[image: Booklet image]

I'm fairly new to designing for print and I was hoping someone would know how to add bleed to a shape like the one below. The printer is requesting bleed of 3mm to add to the image, I have no idea how to add it to an image that's irregular like the one below. any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try Object>Path>Offset Path?

Comment: Hi yes, I did offset path 3mm and extended the artwork to the line when saving it to pdf do I need to include this as bleed? thank you

Comment: This looks like a die cut piece. LeoNas's recommendation is the ticket. Just keep in mind that areas that are supposed to be glued should not have ink. You should consult with your vendor about where the ink voids should be.

Answer (score 2):

A bleed is used to print a slightly larger page, then trim it to size, so that elements that are supposed to continue off the edge of the page (like a background) don't have a gap, even if the cut is slightly off target. If there is supposed to be a white border with nothing printed, you don't need to add anything, but otherwise you probably want to carry on the shape like this:

[image]